# confusion about html5 application project structure in netbeans vs on my local computer

Tags: html, web, netbeans

I'm currently learning html5 web development using netbeans. However, I'm a little bit confused as to how the project structure is arranged in netbeans.

The project structure shown by netbeans IDE is

[image]

However, when I opened the corresponding folder on my local computer, the project structure looks different

[image]

Why the folder names and structure of the project is different when shown in netbeans IDE compared to my local computer? Sorry if this question sounds silly to some of you, but it has caused me a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's structured that way for your convenience. If you click on the files tab (Probably right under the projects tab that you're currently viewing your project in.) and click into the file structure there, it's the same as your local computer. But you don't need to see configuration or build files and Java projects will likely be nested in a bunch of folders. When your project grows, these folders would be a huge eyesore. Netbeans just trims the fat for easy developing.

Netbeans website -> Features -> Easy & Efficient Project Management:

> "Keeping a clear overview of large applications, with thousands of folders and files, and millions of lines of code, is a daunting task. NetBeans IDE provides different views of your data, from multiple project windows to helpful tools for setting up your applications and managing them efficiently, letting you drill down into your data quickly and easily"

https://netbeans.org/features/